# How to handle gRPC errors happening before any Interceptor can be called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, grpc

I've seen many articles dealing about how to make a global error handler for gRPC via an Interceptor class, but my problem is to find a way to handle errors (e.g. log and customize error message) which happen before a gRPC Interceptor can be called.

For example, when clients trying to integrate to your gRPC API, they do mistakes and it can happen that the gRPC request is wrong, it contains such a message (protobuf content) that cannot be deserialized on the server side - based on the data contracts the server uses. (e.g. a field was sent as a string, but it should be an integer)

In such situations, none of the Interceptors can be called and a regular RpcException is thrown and sent back to the client (as an HTTP 200 OK (?!?!?) response) by gRPC framework:
Status = Unkown, Detail = "Exception was thrown by handler."

This is neither much helpful for the client, nor for system operators as it is not logged!
(The only way -I can think of- to "log" is to use a custom ASP.NET Middleware to check every HTTP response and its HTTP headers to search for gRPC specific error related header items).

Question: How to handle a gRPC error happening before Interceptors?

I would expect a gRPC component where I could provide my global, custom error handler where all errors can be caught and -if required- gRPC response can be altered, extended.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Look at sample code at bottom of following : https://grpc.io/docs/guides/error/#:~:text=If%20an%20error%20occurs%2C%20gRPC,clients%20in%20all%20supported%20languages.  There is an invalid argument shown here : https://github.com/avinassh/grpc-errors/blob/master/csharp/Hello/HelloServer/Program.cs

Comment: @jdweng I'm aware of gRPC "rich error model", but -even this guide- does not answer the situation I described: how to catch (and handle: log, provide custom error message, etc.) an error which happens before request is deserialized and a gRPC interceptor or service method is called? How to handle the case in the provided example when HelloReq is sent with an integer field as the first field (string Name = 1 is replaced)? The request cannot be even deserialized on server side!

Comment: There is a listener on the Server and initial connection exception would be caught by the listener (link provided).  If listener did not catch an exception it means the connection did not complete.  The only way of catching exception where connection did not complete is in the client using a timeout exception (not in server).  See : https://techdozo.dev/getting-error-handling-right-in-grpc/

Comment: Errors are handled in layers 1)  Connection issues (including TLS) 2) Authentication issues 3) Routing Issues 4) Processing Issues (including deserialize)